# Add values to key when id inside it exists

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object

I am trying to add data from an array to an object one contains order data and the other contains product data (they can't be combined unfortunately since I am using a payment API).

First I create an object from the orderdata like this:

```
foreach($transactioninfodecoded->saleData->orderData as $orders){
    $totalproductsum = $orders->quantity * $orders->price;

    $prodids[] = $orders->productId;

    $productarray[] = $orders;
}
```

This gives me the following result when I print `$productarray`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [productId] => 10
            [quantity] => 4
            [price] => 150000
            [description] => 
            [productType] => 
            [vatCode] => 
            [vatPercentage] => 
            [discount] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [productId] => 11
            [quantity] => 3
            [price] => 80000
            [description] => 
            [productType] => 
            [vatCode] => 
            [vatPercentage] => 
            [discount] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [productId] => 2
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 100000
            [description] => 
            [productType] => 
            [vatCode] => 
            [vatPercentage] => 
            [discount] => 0
        )

)
```

Then I have a query which gets all products where the ids are that of the productsids like this:

```
$prodidsfinal = implode(',', $prodids);
$productinfo = "SELECT * FROM snm_content WHERE id IN (".$conn->real_escape_string($prodidsfinal).")";
```

Now if the orderid of one is equal to the id of a product, I want to add the title and alias of a product as values to the correct key.

I tried that like this:

```
while($productinfo = $productinfocon->fetch_assoc()){
            // Kijk of productid voorkomt in object en voeg data eraan toe
            if (isset($productarray[1]['productId'][$productinfo['id']])) {
                // Zo ja voeg de titel en alias eraan toe
               $productarray[1]['productId'] = $productinfo['title'];
                 $productarray[1]['productId'] = $productinfo['alias'];
            }
        }
```

(I've just added the `[1]` for now to test if it does what I want, I can loop through the result later and add to the keys when this works.)

But this gives me an error: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

I thought `$productarray[]` would turn it into an array, but apparently not, so I tried the following:

```
while($productinfo = $productinfocon->fetch_assoc()){
            // Kijk of productid voorkomt in object en voeg data eraan toe
            if (isset($productarray->{1}->productId->{[$productinfo['id']]})) {
                // Zo ja voeg de titel en alias eraan toe
               $productarray->{1}->productId = $productinfo['title'];
                 $productarray->{1}->productId = $productinfo['alias'];
            }
        }
```

But when I print `$productarray` again, I get the exact same result as before, just the products but no title and alias added.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit for the first comment:

```
while($productinfo = $productinfocon->fetch_assoc()){
            // Kijk of productid voorkomt in object en voeg data eraan toe
            if (isset($productarray[1]->productId[$productinfo['id']])) {
                // Zo ja voeg de titel en alias eraan toe
               $productarray[1]->productId = $productinfo['title'];
                 $productarray[1]->productId = $productinfo['alias'];
            }
        }
```

I got it to work with the help of Kamran.

My code now:

```
//(inside loop)
$productarray[$orders->productId] = $orders;

while($productinfo = $productinfocon->fetch_assoc()){
            // Kijk of productid voorkomt in object en voeg data eraan toe
            if (isset($productarray[$productinfo['id']])) {
                 // Zo ja voeg de titel en alias eraan toe
               $productarray[$productinfo['id']]->title = $productinfo['title'];
                 $productarray[$productinfo['id']]->alias = $productinfo['alias'];
            }
        }
```

Comment: $productarray is an array which has objects so you will do `$arr[index]->object` to access.Access product id as `$productarray[1]->productId` and that is a value not an object or array.

Comment: So like in my edit? @Kamran

Comment: `$productarray[1]->productId` will return you a value i-e 11 in your array. you will not get this $productarray[1]->productId[$productinfo['id']] `  evaluated beacuse it does not exist. if you want your array to be indexed by product id . do that in `$productarray['product id here'] = $orders`;

Comment: @Kamran Thank you, I fixed it with your help. Solution is in my question.

Comment: you are welocme.